# Access: How to alter column to counter with existing rows in table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ansi-sql-92

I know that  it can't be easily solved by this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE BLOCK ALTER COLUMN block_id COUNTER(5000,1) PRIMARY KEY; 
-- I get here error saying about wrong column type
```

Because of 2 reason:

- the table must be empty
- the table must not already have a    Primary Key

I have such simplified scheme:

[image]

I need to make in `block` table `block_id` column and in `record` table  `record_id` column to be a counter. `Source_id` column in `Source` is already a counter. The problem  here is that tables have connection like shown in the attached  picture. And all this 3 tables are filled with data.

```
Max(block_id)  = 4129
Max(record_id) = 9047
```

And I want to make this columns to be a counter starting from 2 values written before. Is there any solution without making temp tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this without temp tables. The Primary Key is not the problem, but you can never change an INT field to AutoNumber if there is data.

You need to use an Append query (INSERT INTO) to copy the existing IDs into the new table with the AutoNumber.

This link may give you some ideas: [How to reset an AutoNumber field value in Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812718)

Comment: I will handle by creating additional columns and then replace original `id` columns

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work either - you can't UPDATE an AutoNumber column, you can only INSERT it.

Comment: But I did it by updating columns without counter